# Drag and drop a value of a list to random area of the page , is not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Kindly help me with drag and drop a list value from its place to random area of the page, which is I am trying to do with below code block:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

USERINFORMATION=(By.CLASS_NAME,"ex-tree-node-el x-unselectable x-tree-node-expanded")
DESTINAION_BLANKSPACE=(By.CLASS_NAME, "x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-PROFILE")

USERINFORMATION=(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter)]")
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(USERINFORMATION))
element1=WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(USERINFORMATION))
element2=WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(EC.element_to_be_selected(DESTINAION_BLANKSPACE))
#create action chain object
action = ActionChains(browser)
action.dragAndDrop(element1, element2).build().perform();
```

Html code:

```html
<li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-182" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable x-tree-node-expanded" unselectable="on" id="extdd-13"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-minus"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-14"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-15">User Information</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style=""><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-195" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-16"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-17"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-18">First Name</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-196" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-19"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-20"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-21">Last Name</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-197" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-22"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-23"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-24">Title</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-198" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-25"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-26"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-27">Company Name</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-199" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-28"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-29"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-30">Division</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-200" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-31"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-32"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-33">Department</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-201" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-34"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-35"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-36">Employee Number</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-202" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-37"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-38"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-39">Phone</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-203" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-40"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-41"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-42">Mobile</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-204" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-43"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-44"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-45">Fax</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-205" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-46"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-47"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-48">Email</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-206" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-49"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-50"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-51">Delegated Approver</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-207" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-52"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-53"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-54">Full Name</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li><li class="x-tree-node"><div ext:tree-node-id="xnode-208" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable field-letter" unselectable="on" id="extdd-55"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end"><img alt="" src="/s.gif" class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" id="extdd-56"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-57">User ID</span></a></div><ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul></li></ul></li>
```

how the drag and drop is expected

[image]

Let me know if any thing needed towards fix this.

Comment: Looks like Python - should this have a Python tag?

Comment: in the post destination html code is missing hence can't reproduce the case